# How to remove duplicate files inside git repo?

Tags: git

I can see a lot of duplicate files inside my git repo. They look like this:

[image]

How do I remove them without making a fatal mistake?

Comment: Git internally de-duplicates files, so there are no duplicate files in a Git repository. There can be duplicate files in a *checked out* commit, though.

Comment: If you mean that for instance "IPOneTimeCell 2.xib" and "IPOneTimeCell 3.xib" are duplicates then I believe this is something you need to sort out manually because git didn't rename them, that is something you (or Xcode) has done so only you can determine which version is correct and should be kept.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am the only developer and I am quite sure, I never created them. They don't show up inside XCode. These files are only visible in GitHub or in the file directory on my Mac

Answer (score 2):

I do delete All files which end with `space + [digit]`:
`find . -type f -name '* [0-9]' -exec rm {} +`
and run the second which lets me delete files with any format type ( 2.png, 2.md...):
`find . -type f -name '* [0-9].*' -exec rm {} +`

Answer (score 1):

The steps for doing this are:

In the command-line, navigate to your local repository.

Ensure you are in the default branch:

```
git checkout master
```

The rm -r command will recursively remove your folder:

```
git rm -r folder-name
```

Or If you have a matching pattern

```
find ./ -name "pattren" | xargs rm -r
```

Commit the change:

```
git commit -m "Remove duplicated directory"
```

Push the change to your remote repository:

```
git push origin master
```

[Check this official page link for more details](https://github.community/t/how-to-delete-multiples-files-in-github/702)

Answer (score 1):

1. Pull the repository onto your machine
2. Create a new branch and delete the unwanted files
3. Make sure the project still runs and is how you want it
4. Commit your changes and push the new branch to remote
5. Merge your new branch into the original. Verify that the correct files are going to be deleted before you merge.

You emphasized not making a "fatal mistake" and this approach gives you a few opportunities to catch yourself before that happens.